# What sequence is used to delimit HTTP messages?

Tags: http, syntax, format

What is used to separate/delimit HTTP messages in a stream? Are they separated by a double newline (CR LF CR LF), or by status/start lines?

Comment: Can you provide some explanation on "HTTP messages in a stream"? AFAIK, there is only one HTTP message in one HTTP response, the message itself is read as a stream.

Comment: How does a server know when a client's request has been fully transmitted? I'm talking about communicating with HTTP through sockets.

Comment: If the client's HTTP request has body, normally there will be a `Content-Length` header in the request, indicating the bytes number in body. When server receives the request, it will get the body byte by byte, until the received bytes number reach the limit (`Content-Length`). At that moment, the server know the request has been fully transmitted.

Comment: If the client's HTTP request has no body, when server receive & parse the request, an empty line (`CRLF`) will indicate the end of the header section, thus indicate the end of request transmission.